How to use sonar scanned C# proejct on centos
I'm trying to scan a C# project using SonarScanner and encountered some issues.
I followed the steps from the SonarSource documentation.
Here are the details of my environment:
.NET Core SDK version: 3.1.426
dotnet-sonarscanner tool version: 5.15.1
I executed the following commands:
git clone my-project
cd my-project
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.15.0
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools"
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"xxx" -d:sonar.host.url="xxxx" -d:sonar.login="xxxx"
dotnet build ./xxxx/xxx/xx.sln

However, I encountered this error during the build step:
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.426/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks

It seems like the build is failing due to missing reference assemblies for .NET Framework 4.6.2. I'm working in a Linux environment, and I understand that .NET Framework is primarily for Windows.
Could anyone please advise on how I can successfully perform the SonarScanner analysis in this environment? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I tried to google this question, but couldn't find an answer
